# Android Studio App Apk Installation Error

Tags: android

I get this following error every time i try to run my app, wasn't happening couple days ago and i have never seen this before. I am running android studio 4.0

[image]

Stuff i tried

- File -> Invalidate Caches / Restart
- Build -> Build bundle(s) / APK(s) -> Build APK(s)

Comment: The app fas been built but installation on the device fails. I noticed that the path name of the APk is very long. Some Windows applications are restricted to paths up to 255 characters. This APK file name may break this limit which may be the cause for your problem. Close Android Studio and use shorter directory and file names for your project.

Comment: i moved it to a much shorter path and still get the same error, new path is "C:\Users\Daniel Ignjatov\AndroidStudioProjects\InventoryLive\app\build\outputs\apk\debug\app-debug.apk"

Answer (score 1):

**Build Gradel Again (on image mark 1), Then Run the App on Device/Emulator (on image mark 3). If it also don't work restart your android studio and run again.**

[image]

Hope it would solve the issue!

Comment: Using emulator or device?

Comment: emulator, Pixel 3 XL

Comment: Tried another emulator device?

Comment: wow this actually worked, i tried with Pixel XL. How do i get it to work with Pixel 3XL though, I still need to run it on that for my project.

Comment: @Turkehy Recreate virtual device with proper api version then run with it. it would work!